# How to get Facebook posts for og_object or shared url?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Articles from the blogging website get published on multiple Facebook pages and I need to get the list of facebook post urls that contain specific article url.

It is possible to get `og_object` details by article url using this request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/?id=http://spoilednyc.com/2015/02/10/16-bucket-list-must-dos-real-new-yorkers&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The result will be:

```
 "og_object": {
"id": "794284920664423",
"description": "New York City has so much to offer beyond the attractions most known to tourists. Want to go off the beaten path, here are some suggestions for you.",
"title": "Beyond the Tourist Attractions: 16 Bucket List Must-Dos for 'Real' New Yorkers",
"type": "article",
"updated_time": "2016-02-19T11:21:26+0000",
"url": "http://spoilednyc.com/2015/02/10/16-bucket-list-must-dos-real-new-yorkers/"
},
"share": {
"comment_count": 0,
"share_count": 15247
},
"id": "http://spoilednyc.com/2015/02/10/16-bucket-list-must-dos-real-new-yorkers"
}
```

From this point I can find, for example, a list of comments using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/794284920664423/comments/?access_token=Access_Token
```

Is there a way to get Facebook posts or post-ids by `og_object` id in a similar way?